# when i create mvc controller with views,using entityframework i cant route to it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

My control is built well, but I can't get to that path and I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'First_Identity_Project.Models.Utility' while attempting to activate 'First_Identity_Project.Controllers.UsersController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'First_Identity_Project.Models.Utility' while attempting to activate 'First_Identity_Project.Controllers.UsersController'.

Codes in my context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace First_Identity_Project.Models
{
    public class Utility:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> UserTbl { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=firstIdentityDb;user Id = sa;password= Aa123456;Trusted_Connection = true;trustServerCertificate=true;");
        }
    }
}
```

Codes in program.cs file:

```
using First_Identity_Project.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I did not make any changes in the codes inside the controller

Comment: The Error suggests that your UsersController uses Utility but cannot create it. Can you show your controller ? My guess is you forgot to add Utility to dependency injection.

Comment: The error occurs in `UsersController` so please [edit] the question to show its code. If it has lots of action methods, then just show the one that is relevant.

Comment: Add `Utility` to DI.  In `Program.cs` add  `builder.Services.AddDbContext<Utility>(options =>   options.UseSqlServer("connectionString"));`

Answer (score 0):

You put the connectionString inside context, but you still need to add the dbcontext to service in program.cs. Or this dbcontext cannot be resolved.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Utility>();
```

Another pattern is put the the connectionString in program.cs. It will be like

```
    public class Utility : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> UserTbl { get; set; }
        public Utility(DbContextOptions<Utility> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Utility>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=firstIdentityDb;user Id = sa;password= Aa123456;Trusted_Connection = true;trustServerCertificate=true;")
            );
```